# Finding duplicate in an array -- How to make faster?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, duplicates, runtime

I wrote a function that returns true if an array contains duplicates, false otherwise. My runtime is only in the 50th percentile of submissions on Leet Code. Why? Isn't this O(n) and how can you make this faster?

```
def contains_duplicate(nums)
  hsh = Hash.new(0)

  nums.each do |num|
    hsh[num] +=1
    if hsh[num] > 1
      return true
    end
  end
  return false
end
```

[Runtime hash submission only in the 50th percentile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f86On.png)

*Edit
For the curious, here's the link to the coding problem on Leet Code: https:// leetcode.com/problems/contains-duplicate/

Yo peeps, I ran the suggested set code and got an even worse runtime:

```
def contains_duplicate(nums)
  s = Set.new
  nums.each { |num| return true unless s.add?(num) }
  false
end
```

[Runtime set submission in 20th percentile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o53Th.png)

**Fastest running time

```
def contains_duplicate(nums)
  hsh = Hash.new(0)
  count=0
  nums.each do |num|
    count+=1
    hsh[num]=1
    if hsh.size < count
      return true
    end
  end
  return false
end
```

http: //i.stack.imgur.com/Xx21p.png

Comment: Have you profiled it?

Comment: I think `!!nums.dup.uniq!` crushes them all here because [`uniq!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq-21) is crazy fast.

Comment: @tadman Wow, it really surprised me that `uniq!` returns nil when the array is already unique.  Even though that's more concise, I might prefer something like `def has_dups(array); array.size > array.uniq.size; end`.

Comment: Yo I ran !!nums.dup.uniq! and it had the slowest runtime ever. Lower 10% percentile @tadman [lower 10% percentile runtime](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uB0sQ.png)

Comment: That's odd. It's like 30x faster than this on large lists of numbers.

Comment: Alright, Its because i forgot to run the solution ~5 times to get the average. But it got [43 percentile average](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xyRjW.png]) @tadman

Comment: I made an error in my initial benchmark. I've corrected it and added @Matt's method.

Comment: I've had a poke at that site and I think their benchmarks are extremely flawed. The run time of some code varies from 150ms to 250ms because their tests are extremely short. You do need to average them, or just play it like a slot machine and submit over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ruby, but I can see that your loop requires 3 hash lookups per item, and hash lookups are the most expensive operation involved after allocating new items.

Try something like this, which requires only one lookup per item:

```
def contains_duplicate(nums)
  hsh = Hash.new(0)
  count=0
  nums.each do |num|
    count+=1
    hsh[num]=1
    if hsh.size < count
      return true
    end
  end
  return false
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a set.

```
require 'set'

s = Set.new
nums.each { |num| return true unless s.add?(num) }
false
```

See [Set#add?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add-3F).

I wouldn't expect any significant difference with the OP's method, however, as sets are implemented with hashes.

...but let's see.

```
require 'fruity'
```

The methods to be compared are as follows:

```
def hash_way(nums)
  hsh = Hash.new(0)
  nums.each do |num|
    return true if hsh.key?(num)
    hsh[num] = 1
  end
  false
end
```

The above is the OPs code with a small change.

```
def set_way(nums)
  s = Set.new
  nums.each { |num| return true unless s.add?(num) }
  false
end
```

@gonzolo2000's method (since deleted) and @Jack's method, modified slightly:

```
def uniq_way(nums)
  nums.uniq.size < nums.size
end

def hash2_way(nums)
  hsh = Hash.new(0)
  count=0
  nums.each do |num|
    count+=1
    hsh[num]=1
    if hsh.size < count
      return true
    end
  end
  return false
end

def bench(nums, n)
  nums = arr(n)
  compare do 
    _hash  { hash_way(nums) } 
    _set   { set_way(nums) }
    _uniq  { uniq_way(nums) }
    _hash2 { hash2_way(nums) } 
  end
end
```

First consider an array with one duplicated element:

```
def arr(n)   
  ((1..n).to_a << 1).shuffle
end
```

For example,

```
arr(20)
  #=> [17, 12, 1, 20, 3, 10, 15, 9, 5, 2, 14, 1, 18, 16, 7, 13, 19, 4, 8, 11, 6]

bench(nums, 100)
Running each test 128 times. Test will take about 1 second.
_hash2 is similar to _hash
_hash is similar to _uniq
_uniq is similar to _set

bench(nums, 1_000)
Running each test 32 times. Test will take about 1 second.
_hash2 is similar to _hash
_hash is similar to _set
_set is faster than _uniq by 2x ± 1.0

bench(nums, 10_000)
Running each test 2 times. Test will take about 1 second.
_hash2 is similar to _hash
_hash is similar to _set
_set is similar to _uniq

bench(nums, 100_000)
Running each test once. Test will take about 2 seconds.
_hash2 is similar to _hash
_hash is similar to _set
_set is faster than _uniq by 7x ± 1.0

bench(nums, 1_000_000)
Running each test once. Test will take about 51 seconds.
_hash2 is similar to _hash
_hash is faster than _uniq by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
_uniq is similar to _set
```

Now I will change the test data so that 10% of the unique elements of the array have one dup:

```
def arr(n)   
  (1..n).to_a.concat((1..n/10).to_a).shuffle
end
```

For example,

```
arr(30)
  #=> [14, 3, 1, 5, 20, 11, 4, 2, 25, 15, 23, 18, 30, 2, 19, 10, 13,
  #    26, 24, 8, 6, 21, 16, 27, 7, 17, 12, 1, 29, 3, 28, 9, 22] 

bench(nums, 100)
Running each test 512 times. Test will take about 1 second.
_hash2 is similar to _hash
_hash is similar to _set
_set is faster than _uniq by 3x ± 1.0

bench(nums, 1_000)
Running each test 128 times. Test will take about 2 seconds.
_hash2 is similar to _hash
_hash is similar to _set
_set is faster than _uniq by 9x ± 1.0

bench(nums, 10_000)
Running each test 128 times. Test will take about 8 seconds.
_hash2 is similar to _hash
_hash is similar to _set
_set is faster than _uniq by 79x ± 10.0

bench(nums, 100_000)
Running each test 16 times. Test will take about 17 seconds.
_hash2 is similar to _hash
_hash is similar to _set
_set is faster than _uniq by 180x ± 10.0

bench(nums, 1_000_000)
Running each test 4 times. Test will take about 56 seconds.
_hash2 is similar to _hash
_hash is similar to _set
_set is faster than _uniq by 810x ± 100.0
```

Comment: So yeah, hash is the fastest. Set had a slower runtime for the coding problem I linked in my edit.

Comment: The comment above concerned my initial findings, which were in error. I've revised my answer to make the correction and expand the comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

I always like the idea of writing obvious code. Therefore, my personal favorite would look something like this:

```
array.uniq == array
```

And some benchmarks with your original method:

```
a = (1..20).to_a

Benchmark.realtime { 100000.times{ contains_duplicate(a) }}
=> 0.937844

Benchmark.realtime { 100000.times{ a.uniq == a }}
=> 0.804872
```

An also with an array that contains duplicates:

```
a = a * 3

Benchmark.realtime { 100000.times{ contains_duplicate(a) }}
=> 1.068844

Benchmark.realtime { 100000.times{ a.uniq == a }}
=> 0.919273
```

Comment: Comparing the arrays for equality requires comparing every element in the array.  Since we know the unique array is derived from the original array, I don't think there's a need to compare objects, and we could simply use instead: `def has_dups(array); array.size > array.uniq.size; end`.

Comment: yeah and if you use array.uniq thats already O(n) and then comparing the arrays against another is another O(n^2) isn't it.